# Testing response time in Asp.net mvc4 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an asp.net mvc4 application , in which i have this class

```
public class Arbre
{
    public int id_resp = -1;
    Admin notre_admin = new Admin();
    List<Task> _la_liste = new List<Task>();

    public Arbre(int id)
    {
        id_resp = id;
    }

    public List<Task> GetTasksOfExpert(int id_user) {
        List<int> liste =  notre_admin.GetTasksOfExpert(id_user);
        List<Task> liste_finale = new List<Task>();

        for (int i = 0; i < liste.Count; i++) {
            liste_finale.Add(notre_admin.GetTaskListByAffaire(null).Find(x => x.Id_tache == liste[i]));
        }

        return liste_finale;
    }

    public List<Task> GetTasksOfChef(int id_user)
    {
        List<int> liste = notre_admin.GetTasksOfChef(id_user);
        List<Task> liste_finale = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < liste.Count; i++)
        {
            liste_finale.Add(notre_admin.GetTaskListByAffaire(null).Find(x => x.Id_tache == liste[i]));
        }
        return liste_finale;
    }

}
```

I'd like to add a test which helps me to know the approximate time for each method  in order to optimize my code.

- How can i do this?
- Does a unit testing can do this trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ready tools that can help you achieve that. 
One of my favourites is [miniprofiler](http://miniprofiler.com/)

I'd give it a go and see if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of commercial products available that allow you to profile your code ([Ants Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) from RedGate is one that leaps to mind). As Marcom mention [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) is pretty good (and it's free and quite easy to setup and use).

The other more complex alternative is to investigate [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) and implement functionality around your methods that allow you to log the duration. I've used the AOP functionality from [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/) to implement something similar (in combination with Log4Net).

You could use a form of Unit Testing for this, but this is more an [integration test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing) than a Unit Test. (e.g. in your integration test you could setup a timer and measure the method execution duration). Integration tests can be slow to run and you wouldn't necessarily be able to get performance metrics from a production system.